# how to fixe Parse error: syntax error

Tags: php

Hi guys I am trying to get the following code below to work but I got a  `parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"'`

```
$product .= "$item_id-""$length-""$Category-".$each_item['quantity'].",";
```

Basically it is meant to show something like this. `1-12 size-blue-13` the `","`

Comment: you forgot to add a dot between  "$item_id-" and "$length-" and also "$length-" and "$Category-" try this: $product .= "$item_id-"."$length-"."$Category-".$each_item['quantity'].",";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PHP variable interpolation vs concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790501/php-variable-interpolation-vs-concatenation)

---

The correct syntax - 
`$product .= "${item_id}-"."${length}-"."${Category}-".$each_item['quantity'].",";`

Comment: Thanks love, unbelievable what `.` can mean,lol

Comment: Yes, also read this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790501/php-variable-interpolation-vs-concatenation

Comment: Please mark it as the answer or upvote if it is correct.

Comment: 4 minutes until i can mark

Answer (score 2):

With strings you can use braces:

```
$product .= "${item_id}-${length}-${Category}-${each_item['quantity']},";
```