# Adding an HTML link with PHP

Tags: php, html

i have this problem i hope some of you can help me with. I try to make a html link  that get the link from my database.

```
echo "<p><pre><a href=$Feed['socialfacebook']><img src=facebook-24.png></a></pre></p>
```

Comment: It looks like you're missing the double quote at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-quoted strings don't work with array elements quite like that.  You should close and concatenate the strings.

`echo "<p><pre><a href=".$Feed['socialfacebook']."><img src=facebook-24.png></a></pre></p>"`

You might also want to put some quotes on your attributes.

Comment: This worked perfectly! i will accept it in 6 minutes when stackoverflow allows me too! thank you so much! and thanks to all of you guys!

Comment: This answer actually missed the quotes for the html attributes

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the link in `'".$variable ."'` and the image src should be in ' ', too.

```
echo "<p><pre><a href='".$Feed['socialfacebook']."'><img src='facebook-24.png'></a></pre></p>";
```

Comment: Just copy the entire code, works exactly like it should

Comment: Don't forget the closing "; at the end, you did in your question

Answer (score 1):

- Close your string with a double quote and end your statement with a semi-colon,
- When getting array elements inside a string literal like you're doing, leave out the key quotes,
- Use single quotes around your attribute in case of any spaces:

```
echo "<p><pre><a href='$Feed[socialfacebook]'><img src=facebook-24.png></a>";
```

[**Eval.in**](https://eval.in/209517)

Comment: Do you know any difference between `"<a href='$array[key]'>"`, `"<a href='{$array["key"]}'>"` and `"<a href='".$array['key']."'>"` besides readability (performance, compatibility version, ...) ?

Comment: @Brewal See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790501/php-variable-interpolation-vs-concatenation

Answer (score 0):

u need to put the variable `$Feed['socialfacebook']` in `" . $Feed['socialfacebook'] ."`

```
echo "<p><pre><a href=" . $Feed['socialfacebook'] . "<img src=facebook-24.png></a></pre></p>";
```

and don't forget the `;`

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't it be:

```
echo "<p><pre><a href='$Feed["socialfacebook"]'><img src=facebook-24.png></a>";
```

Don't forget that is `href=""`.