# Echoing checkbox values to use for DELETE query is failing

Tags: php, checkbox

I cannot seem to understand why this is not echoing:

```
foreach($_POST["checked"] as $value) {
    echo "$value";
}
```

When I just use the following:

```
echo $_POST['checked'];
```

The value is shown but only for 1 checkbox.

I need to grab all the values of all checked checkboxes.

This is my checkbox:

```
echo '<td><input id="checked" name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="'.$row['id'].'"></td>';
```

Comment: AFAIK, not checked checkbox will not be submitted. At least that's not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are considering `id` attribute where as it is `name` attribute that gets posted.

Change it to:

```
foreach($_POST["checkbox"] as $value) {
  echo $value; // Also, no need of double quotes.
}
```

[PHP variable interpolation vs concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790501/php-variable-interpolation-vs-concatenation)

Comment: I just realised this method would make the query have to run many times, is there a better method to deleting using checkbox?

Comment: Simply, get array of checkbox ids and implode them into a string eg. '12,78,87'. In Delete query, fire query like 'DELETE FROM [table_name] WHERE id IN (checkbox_ids_String)'

Answer (score 0):

The field are named as `checkbox[]` not `checked`.

```
echo '<td><input id="checked" name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="'.$row['id'].'"></td>';
```

Try with -

```
foreach($_POST["checkbox"] as $value) {
    echo "$value";
}
```

Comment: @LuthandoLoot There is a lot of differences between the codes.

Comment: It's funny that this answer gets many downvotes (peak at 3) while Pupil's identical answer below gets upvote.

Comment: @Passerby It happens. Many users downvote without goinn through properly. :)

Answer (score 0):

after using foreach `$value` will also be an `array` like something like below

```
foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $value) {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($value);
    }
```