# PHP password verify

Tags: php, hash, passwords

I cannot verify a password using password_verify. I used BCRYPT for password hashing. Help me find mistake in this code and how do I bind variables in the below select statement:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        // echo "ok";
        $con = connect();
        $email = $_POST['email_id'];
        $pass_word = $_POST['pass_word'];
        if ($con) {
            $query = mysqli_query($con,"select * from login where email_id='".$email."'");
            $rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
            if ($query) {
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
                if ($row) {
                    $hash = $row['password'];
                    if (password_verify($pass_word,$hash) {
                        echo '<strong>Successful' ;
                    } else {
                        echo "Invalid Password";
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            die("Connection Error");
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please close this with the typo reason (my CV aged away). Answering typo questions in the comments and then CVing typo would be what I would do (as opposed to writing up an answer post). You don't get rep, but it's better for the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

missing parenthesis:

change here

```
if(password_verify($pass_word,$hash)
```

to

```
if(password_verify($pass_word,$hash))
```

Extended as request:

```
"select * from login where email_id='".$email."'";
```

becomes

```
"select * from login where email_id= ?";
```

which is passed to the $mysqli::prepare:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM login WHERE email_id= ?");
$stmt->bind_param( "s", $email); // "ss' is a format string, each "s" means string
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($email);// then fetch and close the statement
```

Comment: Actually it was due to copying mistake.Then I realized that I did not hashed all password .So it was not working.Thanks anyway.                  how do i bind variables in the select statement

Comment: `"select * from login where email_id=$email"` this will work as the query is in double quote and you can use interpolation

Comment: Read this , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790501/php-variable-interpolation-vs-concatenation will help you

Comment: no i mean how do i use bind_param() ,prepare() in this case

Answer (score 2):

need a closed parenthes here in

```
if(password_verify($pass_word,$hash)
```

also your query is exposed to sql injection try to prepare it and bind the parameter with

```
$query=$conn->prepare($con,"select * from login where email_id=?");
$query->bind_param('s',$email); //change 's' with 'i' if you are expecting an integer 
$query->execute()//to execute the query
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this for `bind param`

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("select * from login where email_id=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
$stmt->execute();
```